# How to make an HTTP request from SSIS?

Tags: http, ssis

I'm interested in knowing how I can make an HTTP call from SSIS. For example, I would like to be able to download a file from `http://www.domain.com/resource.zip` and record the datetime of the download and the destination of the file on the drive. I would also like to capture such attributes as file size and capture the date & time when the download completed.

Comment: This answer is great, but how would I get things like filesize from the downloaded Uri?
I will need to update the sources table with the filesize information once it has completed

Comment: I don't understand how this isn't built-in to an ETL tool...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can make use of the namespace `System.Net.WebClient` to make the Http request with the help of `Script Task` in SSIS. Following example shows how this can be achieved. The example was created in `SSIS 2008 R2`.

**Step-by-step process:**

1. Create a new SSIS package and create two variables namely **RemoteUri** and **LocalFolder**. Set the variable `RemoteUri` with the value `http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png`. this is the image url of the logo on the Google's home page. Set the variable `LocalFolder` with the value `C:\temp\`. this is the path where we are going to save the content. Refer screenshot #**1**.
2. On the SSIS package, place a `Script Task`. Replace the Main() method within the script task with the code provided under the **Script Task Code** section. Refer screenshot #**2**.
3. Screenshot #**3** shows that the path `C:\temp\` is empty.
4. Screenshot #**4** shows successful execution of the package.
5. Screenshot #**5** shows that the content (in this case the logo image) has been downloaded to the local folder path.
6. Screenshot #**6** shows that the code was tested to download a .zip file. To achieve this, the value of the variable  **RemoteUri**  was changed with the content url that needs to be downloaded.

**Script task code:**

**C#** code that can be used only in **`SSIS 2008 and above`**.

```
public void Main()
{
    Variables varCollection = null;

    Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::RemoteUri");
    Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::LocalFolder");
    Dts.VariableDispenser.GetVariables(ref varCollection);

    System.Net.WebClient myWebClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
    string webResource = varCollection["User::RemoteUri"].Value.ToString();
    string fileName = varCollection["User::LocalFolder"].Value.ToString() + webResource.Substring(webResource.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    myWebClient.DownloadFile(webResource, fileName);

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

**Screenshot #1:**

[image: 1]

**Screenshot #2:**

[image: 2]

**Screenshot #3:**

[image: 3]

**Screenshot #4:**

[image: 4]

**Screenshot #5:**

[image: 5]

**Screenshot #6:**

[image: 6]

Comment: This is helpful, but I'd like more control over my HTTP request -- e.g. POST with a particular request body, which System.Net.WebClient apparently can't do.

Comment: hello please can we download a file from a website that needs a user and password to provide 
i have the user and password but i don't know how to passe it into the programme ?

Answer (score 9):

Just an alternative for @user756519 script, not as fast, but more bulletproof

```
public void Main()
{
    Variables varCollection = null;

    Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::RemoteUri");
    Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::LocalFolder");
    Dts.VariableDispenser.GetVariables(ref varCollection);

    System.Net.WebClient myWebClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
    string webResource = varCollection["User::RemoteUri"].Value.ToString();
    string fileName = varCollection["User::LocalFolder"].Value.ToString() + webResource.Substring(webResource.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);

    byte[] data;
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        data = client.DownloadData(webResource);
    }
    FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(fileName);
    file.Directory.Create(); // If the directory already exists, this method does nothing.
    File.WriteAllBytes(file.FullName, data);

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

This way, webClient doesn't stay hanging, and also you're not dependent on the previous existence of C:\Temp directory.
Other than that, great answer from @user756519, very detailed.

Comment: hello please can we download a file from a website that needs a user and password to provide 
i have the user and password but i don't know how to passe it into the programme ?

Answer (score 6):

Here are a couple of options:

1. Third party tools such as CozyRoc or BlueSSIS.
2. Script Task with WebClient
3. Script Task with HTTP Connection Manager

Script Task Examples at:
http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/05/download-source-file-from-website-with.html

Comment: I thought this was the purpose of the HTTP Connection Manager, but even you list it as the third choice.  Why is this not the go-to option?

Comment: Downside of the HTTP Connection Manager is that it does not support WIndows Authentication