# How to download file from website url using SSIS package

Tags: c#, ssis

I want to download some files from `Website URL` using `SSIS package or c# code`

But the problem is that website is buildup using flash and i need to login first then only 
I can go to homapage from where I need to download 4-5 pdf files

please help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this. [How to make an HTTP request from SSIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684317/making-an-http-request-from-ssis/6684780#6684780) You need to use the exact PDF download url. As long as the file is not restricted by authentication, you should be able to download it.

To pass credentials, look at the *Credentials* property available in the namespace  `System.Net.WebClient`

[WebClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)

[WebClient.Credentials Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.credentials.aspx)

Comment: Thanks But i need to first login into website is there any way to pass credentials too?