# How to fetch the file placed in azure storage container to local machine using SSIS

Tags: asp.net, ssis, azure, azure-sql-database

I want to write a SSIS package to fetch the file placed in my azure storage container to my local machine , can i know any good article which explains it.

Comment: Is your blob container public or private (can you list/get object without authentivation)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way do download singe file is to create Script Task and then use [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx).[`DownloadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx).

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.DownloadFile("url", "localFileName")
}
```

You can also check [How to make an HTTP request from SSIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684317/making-an-http-request-from-ssis/6684780#6684780)