# Fetching files stored in azure container using SSIS - Execute process task

Tags: azure, blob, ssis

Can any one suggest simple example to fetch the file from my windows azure container and place the file on local machine using SSIS - execute process task

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fetch the file placed in azure storage container to local machine using SSIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351354/how-to-fetch-the-file-placed-in-azure-storage-container-to-local-machine-using-s)

Comment: I'm assuming since the same person is asking the question, they felt the original question was answered correctly but did not accurately describe their need.

Comment: Why must the solution use an Execute Process task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this [article](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2010/03/15/Using-FTP-to-access-Windows-Azure-Blob-Storage.aspx), it seems that standard FTP is an option for you. To simplify your life, I'd create an ftp file that performs the download operations and then call that from your Execute Process Task via ftp.

Content of the batch would be approximately

Executable `C:\Windows\System32\ftp.exe`
Arguments  `-s:"C:\myFTPcommands.txt' somewhere.azure.com`

Contents of C:\myFTPcommands.txt would be

```
myusername
myPassword
bin
get myBlob.blob
```

You can test it by opening a command prompt (Win-R cmd) and then calling `ftp -s:"C:\myFTPcommands.txt' somewhere.azure.com`  Once that's working successfully, try it from SSIS.

Reference example of [command line ftp](https://superuser.com/questions/358099/how-do-i-ftp-multiple-files-from-the-command-line/358102)

Comment: Or just use the built-in SSIS [FTP Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137656.aspx) ...

Comment: My assumption was that the FTP task was not up to snuff for connection to Azure which is why OP was looking to use a script task and now execute process task to handle it. I know I had run into limitations with the native task when talking to mainframes so having issues hitting cloud storage didn't seem like a stretch. Point taken though.

Comment: The catch with using FTP is that it depends on someone else's demo azure project.  Or recreating their work.  I suspect the possible duplicate question above is the true answer.