# How to read a specific string from a text file as output variable in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ssis, script-task

I am downloading a webpage as a text file in order to read a specific string to assign it as a variable/parameter in order to create an output file name. I would like to know how would I be able to look for a specific string and output as another variable for the rest of the package.

```html
2015 Conforming Loan Limits

------------------------------------------------------------------------

      o _Loan Limits for Calendar Year 2015--All Counties  _[XLS]
        </DataTools/Downloads/Documents/Conforming-Loan-Limits/FullCountyLoanLimitList2015_HERA-BASED_FINAL_FLAT.xlsx>_ ,
        _[PDF]
        </DataTools/Downloads/Documents/Conforming-Loan-Limits/FullCountyLoanLimitList2015_HERA-BASED_FINAL.pdf>_
        ​
      o _List of 46 Counties with Increases in Loan Limits for 2015
        _[XLS]
        </DataTools/Downloads/Documents/Conforming-Loan-Limits/Counties_with_increases_cy2015_FLAT.xlsx>_
        ​, _[PDF]
        </DataTools/Downloads/Documents/Conforming-Loan-Limits/Counties_with_increases_cy2015.pdf>_
        ​


     


    Previous Announced Loan Limits

------------------------------------------------------------------------

 

*​Description*  *​Format*

​Maximum Loan Limits for Loans (a) Acquired in Calendar Year 2014 and
(b) Originated after 9/30/2011 or Prior to 7/1/2007

 ​[XLS]
</DataTools/Downloads/Documents/Conforming-Loan-Limits/FullCountyLoanLimitList2014_HERA-BASED_FINAL_FLAT.xls>

​Maximum Loan Limits for Loans (a) Acquired in Calendar Year 2013 and
(b) Originated after 9/30/2011 or Prior to 7/1/2007

 

​[XLS]
</DataTools/Downloads/Documents/Conforming-Loan-Limits/FullCountyLoanLimitList2013_HERA-BASED_FINAL.xls>

​Maximum Loan Limits for Loans (a) Acquired in Calendar Year 2012 and
(b) Originated after 9/30/2011 or Prior to 7/1/2007

 

[XLS]
</DataTools/Downloads/Documents/Conforming-Loan-Limits/FullCountyLoanLimitList2012_HERA-BASED_FINAL_Z.xls>
```

To explain it a more better way, I have a sample webpage text here. I should be searching for "FullCountyLoanLimitList" appended by the current year (like FullCountyLoanLimitList2015) and copy the entire file name in the text file and assign it to another variable so that I can download that specific file using WebClient connection.

Please let me know if you need more detailed information for you to help me.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load HTML data into SQL Server (non-table format)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33392585/how-to-load-html-data-into-sql-server-non-table-format)

Comment: As stated in your the answer to your earlier question...using a Script task, you need to parse the output of the resulting web page to locate the URL string, then return it as a read/write variable from the script.  This is not a forum.  You need to show what you have done to try to solve the problem on your, what research you are doing, and reference what part your having trouble with.