# Consuming a REST API row based in SSIS Script Task

Tags: c#, rest, ssis, assemblies, script-task

I am looking for a way to consume a REST API in an SSIS Script Task with C#. I cannot use RestSharp or the Microsoft.Aspnet.Webapi.Client because they are not in the GAC.

I need to call the Rest API (POST) for each row to get a result and then write it back to an output.

Is there a possibility to access a REST API without an assembly?

Comment: Use [`System.Net.WebClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: which version of SSIS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

@l0wsk1ll3d,

I originally asked which version because the more recent the version of SSIS you are working with the more options you have available regarding rest api services.

@stuartd is pointing you to a general way in which you can tap into making requests. This question has been addressed very well in a post by @mikeTheLiar (ironically, Mike is truthful here! :)) Here is the posted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684317/how-to-make-an-http-request-from-ssis).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using Visual Studio 2015 with Integration Services Designer Version 13.0 and Data Tools 14.0. The Script Task is using .NET 4.5 as far as I can see.
When adding
`using System.Net.WebClient;`
I get an error that WebClient could not be found in Namespace "System.Net" and that I should add an reference to the assembly. However the assembly "System.Net.WebClient" is not in the reference manager.

Comment: Try using System.Net.Http and System.Net.Http.HttpClient in order work with Rest services.