# HTTP-GET via SSIS

Tags: ssis, http-get

I have some ethernet device which collect data and it's possible to download it via data export interface: HTTP-GET query returns the data in [Content-Type: text/plain Charset: utf-8]

I saw this: [How to make an HTTP request from SSIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684317/how-to-make-an-http-request-from-ssis/63250016#63250016) - it rather doesn't work for me (C# is a little Chinese for me) and it's about how to fetch this data to variable into SSIS

Comment: This question is likely to get closed as you didn't really ask anything. But the easiest way to access an API is using WebClient in C#. 2 lines gets you the string.  System.Net.WebClient wc = new WebClient(); string response = wc.DownloadString([url]);

Comment: thank's - that works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

In your SSIS package add a C# Script Task

Edit the Script Task

1. At the top with the other using statements add `using System.Net;`
2. in *Main* use the following code snippet to make a GET request (Note: *Change "https://somewhere.com/contacts/get" to your actual endpoint.*)

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://somewhere.com/contacts/get");
    request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

    using(HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    using(Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```